# Fragments - Tabs - Progress Dialog

Tags: android-fragments, progressdialog, android-tabs

Good evening,
I have implemented an application which has 3 tabs (fragments) using TabsListener.
I am trying to display a progress dialog while I press a specific button on the first Tab-fragment. The problem is that the progress dialog never shows up and everything else works fine.
I am quite new to android and I am sure that the answer is quite easy but I have spent many hours on this trying to figure out the solution.
Below is my code

`public class AFragment extends DialogFragment {
    static TextView tx;
    Button bt;
    OnClickListener handler1;
    OnClickListener handler2;
    SQLiteDatabase mydb;
    int counter=0;
    private Button mStartActivityButton;
    public final static String ProgressInsert = "Please wait while data is being inserted...";
    public final static String ProgressSelect = "Please wait while your query is being executed ...";

    /**/

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view;
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.afragment, container, false);
        final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(view.getContext());
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setMessage("Working...");
        pd.isIndeterminate();
        //pd.setContentView(view);
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        tx = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        bt = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mStartActivityButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.start_file_picker_button);

        mStartActivityButton.setOnClickListener(handler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 ((MainActivity) getActivity()).Browse_Button(view.getContext());
             }
        });
        bt.setOnClickListener(handler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {/////////This is the button i press and i want the progress dialog to appear!
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pd.show();
                tx.setText(((MainActivity) getActivity()).ShowRecs());  
                pd.hide();
            }
          });

        return view;
    }//////End of onCreateView!!!!!

    protected static void settxt(StringBuilder textt)
    {

        //mFilePathTextView.setText(textt);
        tx.setText(textt);
    }

}//////////End of Afragment Class!!!!!!!!!!!!`